# Detect touch on subview

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, touch

I have a `Viewcontroller` with two `UIViews`, one named `textureView` and one `objectView`.

When I only have one view I detect touch using this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSArray *allTouches = [touches allObjects];

    for (UITouch *touch in allTouches)
    {
        gestureStartPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
            if([touch view] == controlUIImageview){
                   NSLog(@"TOUCH DETECT");
                }
        }
}
```

How do I write this part if I have some things I want to interact with in the `textureView` and some in the `objectView`?

Do I need to set the `textureView` and`controlView` to `setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE` ?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried setting textureView and controlView to setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE ?  What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 6):

Other way to do this:

```
        gestureStartPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        if(CGRectContainsPoint(textureView.frame, gestureStartPoint)){
            ...
        }
        if(CGRectContainsPoint(objectView.frame, gestureStartPoint)){
            ...
        }
```

Comment: Yes this works also but how do I detect a touch on an uiimageview in a specific uiview? Because [touch view] == uiimageview doesn't work for me when the uiimageview is in a subview.

Comment: it is certainly distorted, but you can use something like this: `CGRect rect1=[self.view convertRect:textureView.controlUIImageview.frame toView:self.view];   if(CGRectContainsPoint(rect1, gestureStartPoint)) ...`

Answer (score 3):

Try to add a `tag` for each subviews you want to add....like:

```
textureView.tag=0;
objectView.tag=1;
```

then:

```
for (UITouch *touch in allTouches)
    {
     if(touch.view.tag==0){
        //...do your stuff with textureView
     }else{
        //...do your stuff with objectView
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes it works for detecting the different views, but how do I detect a touch on an uiimageview in a specific uiview?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to do that, if you want to detect touch on any view you need to setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE, or make enable in IB(if you are adding view's from IB).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the **Singleton Approach**

For example you have UIImageView as subview in TextureView

Make a class e.g object.h and Declare the subview you want to interact with E.g

```
UIImageView *DisplayPicture
UIView *View;
```

Once thats done. You can set Tags for each of the Two Views

```
TextureView.tag=0;
Objectview.tag=1;
```

Than use this method to get the Touch on the View and than Subviews

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];


if (touch.view.tag > 0) {


    NSLog(@"%d",[touch.view.subviews count]);

    //Get Reference for Texture view

    object.View=Touch.view;

    //the index will the position at which u added the Subview(UIImageView) e.g If its the first time you addsubview and index of the subview will be O.

    object.DipslayPicture=[touch.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0];

}else{
  //Similar for ObjectView

}
NSLog(@"tag=%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", touch.view.tag]);
i=touch.view.tag;
}
```

Than you can use the object to do as you like e.g SetImage

```
[object.DisplayPicture setImage:@"happiness.png"];
```

It worked for me :) Hope it helps someone :)